# How can fix this error in python " ProgrammingError: 1064,"

Tags: python, django

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                       File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner                                                          response = get_response(request)                                                                                                                                     File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response                                                      response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)                                                                                                          File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response                                                      response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)                                                                                              File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\ime360ehs\views.py", line 792, in createOrder                                                                                        cursor.execute(query + category_condition2 + " ORDER BY category")                                                                                                   File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute                                                             return super().execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                                  File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute                                                              return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)                                                                                  File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers                                               return executor(sql, params, many, context)                                                                                                                          File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute                                                             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                              File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in **exit**                                                                      raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value                                                                                                          File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute                                                             return self.cursor.execute(sql)                                                                                                                                      File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 74, in execute                                                         return self.cursor.execute(query, args)                                                                                                                              File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute                                                                      res = self._query(query)                                                                                                                                             File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 315, in _query                                                                       db.query(q)                                                                                                                                                          File "D:\current_task\Django\360ehs\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 239, in query                                                                    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)                                                                                                                               django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY category' at line 1")

```
category_condition1 = ""
    category_condition2 = ""
    count_left = 0
    count_right = 0
    category_counts = "SELECT category, COUNT(category) FROM tbl_products GROUP BY category ORDER BY COUNT(category) DESC"
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(category_counts)
        category_counts_arr = cursor.fetchall()
    for category in category_counts_arr:
        if count_left <= count_right:
            if category_condition1 == "":
                category_condition1 += " category = '" + category[0] + "'"
            else:
                category_condition1 += " OR category = '" + category[0] + "'"
            count_left += category[1]
        else:
            if category_condition2 == "":
                category_condition2 += " category = '" + category[0] + "'"
            else:
                category_condition2 += " OR category = '" + category[0] + "'"
            count_right += category[1]
    
    query = "SELECT id, product_code, category, description FROM tbl_products WHERE"
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query + category_condition1 + " ORDER BY category")
        ordersheet1 = cursor.fetchall()
```

this is working another server but this is not working on my local

Comment: **DO NOT** try to create a query string by concatenating a bunch of string bits together, especially if it involves variable data coming from somewhere else. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Anyway, did you at least try to check what the query string ends up as?

Comment: why is your error message 1 big string